# Sql server reader is not reading the data in asp.net MVC-5

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-2014

I am working on asp.net MVC 5, i have placed a bootstrap toggle switch in my page like bellow

[image]

I am inserting data into my Database whenever i switch it from **On-Off** or **Off-to** this switching is based upon my serial number which i have to select and then after performing switch the insert query works

At this point i am able to insert the data properly

Now, if there are multiple On/Off for a particular serial number, then the last command name (On or Off) while be on toggle, i.e. if the last switch was **off** then on selecting the same serial number the toggle should show the switch to OFF

For this i have prepared a query in SQL and it's giving me the latest value for the On or Off case

Bellow is my code in which i have placed my query for fetching

```
con.Open();
                SqlCommand fetch_cmd = new SqlCommand("select TOP 1 ADC.Server_Device_Command_ID as Server_Device_Command_ID , ADC.Device_ID as Device_ID,ADC.Server_Command_ID as Server_Command_ID, ASD.Command_Name as Command_Name from ADS_Server_Device_Command ADC " +
                                                       " inner join ADS_Server_Command ASD on adc.Server_Command_ID = asd.Server_Command_ID " +
                                                       " inner join ADS_Device dsn on adc.Device_ID = dsn.Device_ID " +
                                                       " where dsn.Device_Serial_Number = " + serial_number +
                                                       " order by adc.Server_Device_Command_ID desc", con);


                //fetch_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serial_number", serial_number);


                SqlDataReader s_dr = fetch_cmd.ExecuteReader();
                s_dr.Read();
                con.Close();
```

On quick watch i am getting bellow results

[image]

[image]

Bellow is my Script for Toggle

```
<script>
var search = '@Session["search"]';
var data = {}

    $("#test_id").on("change", function (event) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            //alert("ON");
            data = "On";
        } else {
            //alert("Off");
            data = "Off";
        }
         $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("MultiGraph")',
             data: { data:data , search:search},
         });
    });   </script>
```

In above razor the `var search = '@Session["search"]';`contains the serial number

I must be missing something that i don't know

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Try to isolate the problem by testing the single pieces one by one (SQL query, SQL caller, bootstrap switch running a JS function, connection of the JS function and the SQL query caller or whatever component lies inbetween). Put in lots of debugging log lines so you can see what the back-end is doing at all times.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak yes i have debug a lot but couldn't find the mistake

Comment: As I said, test the parts one by one. You'll strumble upon the bug eventually

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Why the line that should add the parameter is commented?

Second: use SQL Server Profiler to capture the query that your MVC app is executing against the Database. With that, you'll know if the query is returning the result set as expected. (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21371/SQL-Server-Profiler-Step-by-Step)